# Compiling an app that works in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uikit, ios7

I'm struggling to compile an iPad app for use on iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Here's the message I keep getting:

```
Property 'barTintColor' not found on object of type 'UITabBar *'; did you mean 'tintColor'?
```

The `Base SDK` for the target is set to `Latest iOS (iOS 7.0)`, and the `iOS Deployment Target` is `iOS 6.0`.  I did a Clean on the project.

[image: Xcode Target Settings]

Here is the code:

In the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabbedBar;
```

In the .m file:

```
if ([tabbedBar respondsToSelector: @selector(barTintColor)]) {
     tabbedBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

I'm compiling against the iOS 7 SDK, so it should know about barTintColor.  Any idea what the problem could be?

**Updated:**

Okay, I'm making progress, but not quite understanding why.

See this Xcode screenshot.  Note the two entries for my iPad 3 in the Active Scheme selection.  What is the difference?  If I choose the top option, I get the error.  If I choose the bottom option, it works.

[image: Xcode device selection]

Can anyone explain why the same device appears twice in this list, and why it works when I choose one and not the other?  FYI, the device has iOS 6 installed.

Comment: Is that a runtime or compile error? Can you try `@selector(setBarTintColor:)`?

Comment: have you tried the selector setBarTintColor: ?  As in [tabbedBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: Sorry, Xcode doesn't know about `setBarTintColor` either.  See this screenshot [link](http://i.imgur.com/kN0Qu7N.png)

Comment: You did something wrong. Maybe Clean project or quit Xcode and run again? I've set `Latest iOS 7 SDK` and `Target to 6.0` and it is working for me. And in `@selector()` you have to type `setBarTintColor:` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Something is squirrelly here.  If I quit Xcode, restart, clean the app, then run on an iOS 7 iPad, it's fine.  Try the same routine with an iOS 6 iPad, and I get the error.  I don't understand...

Comment: Hmm. I see my plugged in iOS device listed twice too in Xcode 5. I just put it down to it being Xcode and thus I expect that kind of thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two SDKs installed in your Xcode: for iOS 6 and iOS 7. Now, when that happens, if you plug in your iOS 7 device, it shows as two devices (i.e. options) in the device selector: first row is for iPad 3 (iOS 6), second for iPad 3 (iOS 7).

The problem with your error is that when you select iPad 3 (iOS 6), Xcode still *reads* the device as iOS 7 (and that's what it has installed, anyway) so when building it passes the `[tabbedBar respondsToSelector: @selector(barTintColor)]` code (it responds to the selector, 'cause hey, it's iOS 7), but because you're building for iOS 6, at the same time it raises an error, 'cause hey, iOS 6 doesn't have that method! Fun.

Basically, you can't use the iOS 6 option when testing on the iOS 7 device. You either need a iOS 6 device, or you're stuck with the simulator for testing old versions.

EDIT: You can test what I'm saying in the following manner — instead of using `respondsToSelector:` use

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
    // code
}
```

and then select the first device in the list (iPad 3 iOS 6). You'll see that you go through the `if` clause, but Xcode gives you an error that the selector isn't available on iOS 6.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Shouldn't one binary be created regardless if the device has iOS 6 or iOS 7?  When you ship to the App Store, or for Enterprise Distribution, you only build one version.  Not one for each SDK.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking only for running on the iPad. When you archive the app, it works well on both iOS 6 and 7. You can try making an archive and distributing through TestFlight/HockeyApp and you won't have problems.

Comment: So Xcode compiles specific SDK versions when testing, not universal binaries?

Comment: I don't know if that's the case. In any case, it checks for unavailable API calls now (4.x didn't do this), and since there is a code path which leads to the iOS 7 selector (and you're building to run on iOS 6) it raises an error. This is generally a good thing, but can be confusing.